# C# "implicit" downcast?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, implicit, downcast

Is possible to get the lower class of an inheritance at runtime without explicit cast?

Lets say we have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
class A {
    int _a;
}

class B : A {
    int _b;
}

class C : A {
    int _c;
}
```

And I have a generic method somewhere in the code.

```
void Foo<T> (T t) where T : A;
```

In the situation I have a list of references of the object `A` but I have to call `Foo` and pass to `Foo` the lower object type of the instance. In other method this list is fed with the `A` reference of some instances of `B` and other instances of `C`.

I want to be able to call `Foo` with the lower level of the instance without explicit casting. In my real situation I have tons of `B`s and `C`s inheriting from `A` and I there are a few methods which I have to do this job (I mean, this "implicit" downcast). I have to do something like this below.

In some place:

```
A tmp = new C();
```

In other place:

```
Foo<typeof(tmp).SomeMagicMethod()>(tmp);
```

The `Type.SomeMagicMethod` should be anything that I could use to implicit get the lower level of "tmp".

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me, please reformulate it...

Comment: `Foo<typeof(tmp).SomeMagicMethod()>(tmp);` is not valid; generics is a compile-time feature. `T` must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Hello @CommuSoft. I don't know how be more specific. Let me try to sum up my real problem. I have a application which implements a consumer/producer threading pattern. In the producer thread the list in my example are being fed with a high object of my inheritance tree to be able to store all the types of the inheritance. In my consumer thread I want to get these base-class references of the inheritance and implicit get the derivated class type in the inheritance tree of the reference I have in the list to be able to correct call a generic method which should receive the lowest derivated class

Comment: Not at compile time, you could use reflection, etc. But that's all quite inefficient and is asking for trouble...

Comment: I see @Blorgbeard. So... Could you please read my comment above and try to shed some light on the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is **NO**, you can't provide a non-explicit `type` for a generics in C#. This is done by design, as you have to provide full information about the type of variable you provide in method.

From other hand, you can remove the `generic` part of the method, and call it without type parameter. As you've already provide the type for the `tmp`, compiler will use that information for a generic type selection:

```
Foo(tmp);
```

See also [Great Eric Lippert's answer for related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4976972/213550).

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasnt looking at the basics hehe.